# Fetch list value based on a value from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, list-comprehension

I have this list in `Python`:

`fruit = ['apple','grape','watermelon','pineapple']`

And another list like that:

`idx_list = [1,3]`

Now, I need to match each value from `idx_list` with the indexes in the `fruit` to get a new list with values from `fruit` list using `list comprehension`.

Like this:

`['grape','pineapple']`

I'm trying to use this command `[f for f in fruit.columns]` but I'm only getting the values from `fruit.`

Comment: Why did you expect `fruit.columns` to be a thing? Lists don't have a `columns` attribute, and `fruit` doesn't even store columnar data. Are you getting things mixed up with a different data type?

Comment: Because I needed the column names from fruit based in the values into idx_list. Like the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
fruit = ['apple','grape','watermelon','pineapple']
idx_list = [1,3]
print([fruit[i] for i in idx_list])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need.